# Use ms-rest-azure to authenticate with azure-keyvault?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-keyvault, azure-api-apps, azure-cli

I have a node project and I am using these libraries:

```
import { KeyVaultClient } from "azure-keyvault";
import * as msRestAzure from 'ms-rest-azure';
```

Here are the link to them:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-keyvault
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms-rest-azure
```

I am trying to use the azure-keyvault to get secret in my vault.

```
let vaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
vaultClient.getSecret(secretURI)
        .then(function (result) {
            CLogger.log("error", "Result: "+JSON.stringify(result));
            return result.value.toString();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            CLogger.log("error", "Error occurred while getting the secret "+secretName+": " + JSON.stringify(error));
            throw "Error occurred while getting secret. Check log files" ;
        })
```

I am using ms-rest-azure to get the credentials (tokens).  This is mainly because I need to both login using ServicePrincipalSecret and MSI.  As far as I can tell the adal library doesn't support MSI login.

```
import * as msRestAzure from 'ms-rest-azure';
msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientID, clientKey, domainID)
```

And I am indeed getting a login token correctly:

```
{
   "environment":{
      "validateAuthority":true,
      "name":"Azure",
      "portalUrl":"https://portal.azure.com",
      "publishingProfileUrl":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254432",
      "managementEndpointUrl":"https://management.core.windows.net",
      "resourceManagerEndpointUrl":"https://management.azure.com/",
      "sqlManagementEndpointUrl":"https://management.core.windows.net:8443/",
      "sqlServerHostnameSuffix":".database.windows.net",
      "galleryEndpointUrl":"https://gallery.azure.com/",
      "activeDirectoryEndpointUrl":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "activeDirectoryResourceId":"https://management.core.windows.net/",
      "activeDirectoryGraphResourceId":"https://graph.windows.net/",
      "activeDirectoryGraphApiVersion":"2013-04-05",
      "storageEndpointSuffix":".core.windows.net",
      "keyVaultDnsSuffix":".vault.azure.net",
      "azureDataLakeStoreFileSystemEndpointSuffix":"azuredatalakestore.net",
      "azureDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogAndJobEndpointSuffix":"azuredatalakeanalytics.net"
   },
   "authorizationScheme":"Bearer",
   "tokenCache":{
      "_entries":[
         {
            "tokenType":"Bearer",
            "expiresIn":3599,
            "expiresOn":"2018-02-06T22:00:45.439Z",
            "resource":"https://management.core.windows.net/",
            "accessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlNT...",
            "isMRRT":true,
            "_clientId":"51dc31c8-27e7-4a05-9d6b-62c0710c2ad3",
            "_authority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0"
         }
      ]
   },
   "clientId":"51dc31c8-...",
   "domain":"3a41ae53-...",
   "secret":"k7JlWcPdpK...",
   "context":{
      "_authority":{
         "_log":{
            "_componentName":"Authority",
            "_logContext":{
               "correlationId":"ceb8d4fe-135c-48a3-8b19-f50310c026b9"
            }
         },
         "_url":{
            "protocol":"https:",
            "slashes":true,
            "auth":null,
            "host":"login.microsoftonline.com",
            "port":null,
            "hostname":"login.microsoftonline.com",
            "hash":null,
            "search":null,
            "query":null,
            "pathname":"/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0",
            "path":"/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0",
            "href":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0"
         },
         "_validated":true,
         "_host":"login.microsoftonline.com",
         "_tenant":"3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0",
         "_authorizationEndpoint":null,
         "_tokenEndpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0/oauth2/token",
         "_deviceCodeEndpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0/oauth2/devicecode",
         "_isAdfsAuthority":false,
         "_callContext":{
            "options":{

            },
            "_logContext":{
               "correlationId":"ceb8d4fe-135c-48a3-8b19-f50310c026b9"
            }
         }
      },
      "_oauth2client":null,
      "_correlationId":null,
      "_callContext":{
         "options":{

         },
         "_logContext":{
            "correlationId":"ceb8d4fe-135c-48a3-8b19-f50310c026b9"
         }
      },
      "_cache":{
         "_entries":[
            {
               "tokenType":"Bearer",
               "expiresIn":3599,
               "expiresOn":"2018-02-06T22:00:45.439Z",
               "resource":"https://management.core.windows.net/",
               "accessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi...",
               "isMRRT":true,
               "_clientId":"51dc31c8-27e7-4a05-9d6b-62c0710c2ad3",
               "_authority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0"
            }
         ]
      },
      "_tokenRequestWithUserCode":{

      }
   }
}
```

But I am getting a 401 error, what am I doing wrong?

```
{
   "statusCode":401,
   "request":{
      "rawResponse":false,
      "queryString":{

      },
      "url":"https://myVault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mySecret/?api-version=2016-10-01",
      "method":"GET",
      "headers":{
         "x-ms-client-request-id":"95251650-6fcc-467b-8cd7-a23bf22a7a3c",
         "accept-language":"en-US",
         "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         "user-agent":"Node/v6.11.2 (x64-Windows_NT-10.0.16299) ms-rest/2.3.0 ms-rest-azure/2.5.2 azure-keyvault/2.0.1-preview Azure-SDK-For-Node"
      },
      "body":null
   },
   "response":{
      "body":"",
      "headers":{
         "cache-control":"no-cache",
         "pragma":"no-cache",
         "expires":"-1",
         "server":"Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
         "www-authenticate":"Bearer authorization=\"https://login.windows.net/3a41ae53-fb35-4431-be7b-a0b3e1aee3c0\", resource=\"https://vault.azure.net\"",
         "x-ms-keyvault-region":"westus2",
         "x-ms-request-id":"75929ac8-f1ed-441d-9ed0-82ab23c86be5",
         "x-ms-keyvault-service-version":"1.0.0.839",
         "x-aspnet-version":"4.0.30319",
         "x-powered-by":"ASP.NET",
         "strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains",
         "x-content-type-options":"nosniff",
         "date":"Tue, 06 Feb 2018 21:00:45 GMT",
         "connection":"close",
         "content-length":"0"
      },
      "statusCode":401
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your token, the resource is wrong.

You should use `https://vault.azure.net` instead of `https://management.core.windows.net/`.

> This is mainly because I need to both login using
>   ServicePrincipalSecret and MSI. As far as I can tell the adal library
>   doesn't support MSI login.

Yes, `msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientID, clientKey, domainID)` does not support MSI login, but you could use `msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});`

More information about this see this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/).

Comment: Hi, you also could check this [sdk](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/ms-rest-azure/latest/global.html#withServicePrincipalSecret) with `withServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain, optionsopt, optionalCallbackopt) → {function|Promise}`. Maybe you could try to set `environment`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good at node js. In java, I could create auth file like this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md)  `managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/` Hope it helps.

Comment: But I more suggest you use `msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});` Now, you use MSI login, this method is more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Oh we shelved this project so I am not sure if this will work, it looks good though so I will mark it as resolved.